# What is this face doing underneath my world?

Tags: godus

My people refused to settle in a particular area of my world, so I dug away at the landscape to try and work out (think there would be diamonds or something under there) but instead I found a face:

[image]

What is this face doing underneath my world?

Comment: Why, clearly it's taking a nap, duh.

Comment: A monument to a long lost god that popped too many bubbles, it's finger broke and was unable to terraform any longer, then the world continued and grow over it.  Now you've found it, and like Pandora opening the box, it will soon awaken and threaten your reign with a new grander, prettified (not petrified?) finger of awesomeness.....or something else.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions Oh, this would make a perfect answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it's only an easter egg for now, [according to the FAQ on the wiki](http://godus.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Frequently_asked_questions&mobileaction=view_normal_site#What.27s_underneath_the_mountain_north_of_the_Temple_of_Fertility.3F).